# PHP Set image source for image tag

Tags: php

I'm trying to use PHP to get a list of images in a folder and display it.
Here is my current code:

```
$images = glob($volumePath."*");
foreach($images as $image) {
    $path = str_replace('C:\xampp\htdocs\\', '..', $image]);
    $path2 = str_replace(' ', '%20', $path);
    $file = "<img src=".$path2."/>";
    echo $file;
}
```

Right now, it can retrieve the array of images but when I try to display it, it shows the generic placeholder image. How do I get it to show an image?

Tested with giving it the file path and it shows but doesn't work with php.

Comment: What is `$volumePath` set to

Comment: what is `$page`? where did it come from?

Comment: It's passed through $_GET['dirpath'] which is varies. Usually "C:\xampp\htdocs\\Foldername1\Date\imagefile.extension" format. $page was testing the image array

Comment: The subfolders are passed from $dirpath = $_GET['dirpath']; into $volumePath = $dirpath.$volume.'\\';

Comment: Run the page in your browser, use the `page source` to view what is in the `src=""` that should show you what is missing for a full path to the images. Use the browsers debugger and you can even edit the content of `src=` until you see a actual image then you will know what you need to fo in the PHP code to make the right directory structure

Comment: @Akito, ok, show the current `$volumePath` value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this complete code:

```
$images = glob($volumePath."*");
foreach($images as $key => $image) {
    $path = str_replace('C:\xampp\htdocs\\', '../', $image);
    $path2 = str_replace(' ', '%20', $path);
    $file = "<img src='".$path2."'/>";
    echo $file;
}
```

Note the single quotes in the `$file` variable, the modified `foreach` statement and the single `$image` variable in `$path`

Comment: Tried your code and I'm still getting placeholders.

Comment: You are not telling us all the story. See the edition and try again.

Comment: Replacing with `../` :). Please, upvote this answer. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You are using array variable inside foreach which should be `$image`, try following code it might help to solve this issue.

```
$images = glob($volumePath."*");
foreach($images as $image) {
$path = str_replace('C:\xampp\htdocs\\', '..', $image[$page]);
$path2 = str_replace(' ', '%20', $path);
$file = "<img src='".$path2."'/>";
echo $file;
```

Comment: I'm still getting placeholder images.

Comment: Can you share output HTML?